# OnActionExecuting constructing a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Apologises if this is obvious, but I am trying to make the an attribute that handling a caching of the model used in a partial view.

```
  [MyCache(typeof(MyModel))]
  public ActionResult MyAction(string fooId)
  {
      return PartialView(new MyModel());
  }
```

My attribute is supposed to update the cache with the input model on post, and override the actions result on get with my cached model.

However I don't know how to call the PartialView method from outside the contoller. This constructor doesn't seem to have any arguments:

```
  new PartialViewResult(filterContext.HttpContext.Cache.Get("MyModelCache")[model.Name]);
```

How can I construct the model using the razor view? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = 
    filterContext.HttpContext.Cache.Get("MyModelCache")[model.Name];
filterContext.Result = new PartialViewResult
{
    ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData,
    ViewName = "~/Views/_NameOfPartial", // optional if you need it
};
```

Here is the source of the `PartialView` method in a controller that takes 2 arguments:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, (etc)
    {
        ...
        protected internal virtual PartialViewResult PartialView(
            string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (model != null)
                this.ViewData.Model = model;
            PartialViewResult partialViewResult = new PartialViewResult();
            partialViewResult.ViewName = viewName;
            partialViewResult.ViewData = this.ViewData;
            partialViewResult.TempData = this.TempData;
            partialViewResult.ViewEngineCollection = this.ViewEngineCollection;
            return partialViewResult;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the more complete answer! Are tempdata and ViewEngineCollection not needed then?

Comment: Should not be needed unless your partial view uses tempdata or needs a custom view engine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
new PartialViewResult
{
    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(filterContext.HttpContext.Cache.Get("MyModelCache"))[model.Name],
}
```